# Determine whether CPU, RAM or hard drive is bottleneck for Ruby script

Tags: ruby, performance

I'm planning on purchasing a new Mac desktop soon, and I want to know whether CPU, RAM or my hard drive is my bottleneck for my script.

I ran my main unit tests with Ruby 1.9.3 on Ubuntu 12.04 and got the following information:

```
$ date; /usr/bin/time --verbose ruby1.9.1 test/test_all.rb ; date
Mon May  7 15:04:38 EST 2012
Run options: 

# Running tests:

[snip 705 dots]

Finished tests in 50.672999s, 13.9127 tests/s, 49.1781 assertions/s.

705 tests, 2492 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
    Command being timed: "ruby1.9.1 test/test_all.rb"
    User time (seconds): 29.25
    System time (seconds): 5.26
    Percent of CPU this job got: 67%
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:51.01
    Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
    Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
    Average stack size (kbytes): 0
    Average total size (kbytes): 0
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 238592
    Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 4180160
    Voluntary context switches: 31187
    Involuntary context switches: 12397
    Swaps: 0
    File system inputs: 0
    File system outputs: 224
    Socket messages sent: 0
    Socket messages received: 0
    Signals delivered: 0
    Page size (bytes): 4096
    Exit status: 0
Mon May  7 15:05:29 EST 2012
```

As the time taken by user plus system is less than the wall time, I assume CPU isn't the sole bottleneck. How can I work out what else is the bottleneck?

Answer (score 2):

You can analyze your program's memory performance (i.e. how well it utilizes the cache) using [valgrind's](http://www.valgrind.org/) cachegrind tool.

```
$ valgrind --tool=cachegrind ruby ./hello.rb
==7082== Cachegrind, a cache and branch-prediction profiler.
==7082== Copyright (C) 2002-2008, and GNU GPL'd, by Nicholas Nethercote et al.
==7082== Using LibVEX rev 1884, a library for dynamic binary translation.
==7082== Copyright (C) 2004-2008, and GNU GPL'd, by OpenWorks LLP.
==7082== Using valgrind-3.4.1-Debian, a dynamic binary instrumentation framework.
==7082== Copyright (C) 2000-2008, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7082== For more details, rerun with: -v
==7082== 
hello world
==7082== 
==7082== I   refs:      14,529,000
==7082== I1  misses:        24,856
==7082== L2i misses:         6,707
==7082== I1  miss rate:       0.17%
==7082== L2i miss rate:       0.04%
==7082== 
==7082== D   refs:       7,110,663  (4,572,482 rd   + 2,538,181 wr)
==7082== D1  misses:        48,207  (   33,427 rd   +    14,780 wr)
==7082== L2d misses:        16,350  (    3,821 rd   +    12,529 wr)
==7082== D1  miss rate:        0.6% (      0.7%     +       0.5%  )
==7082== L2d miss rate:        0.2% (      0.0%     +       0.4%  )
==7082== 
==7082== L2 refs:           73,063  (   58,283 rd   +    14,780 wr)
==7082== L2 misses:         23,057  (   10,528 rd   +    12,529 wr)
==7082== L2 miss rate:         0.1% (      0.0%     +       0.4%  )
```

Concerning disk performance, I believe that a program with no disk/io usage would run almost entirely in user time, leading me to believe that your hard drive might be at least one of your bottlenecks.  Perhaps there's someone out there who can recommend a good tool for profiling a program's disk usage?